# iOS 10 - WLAN Access Setting Doesn't Appear In Some iOS Devices

Tags: ios, ios10

Our app is using WLAN to communicate with a wireless device. When our app is installed in iOS 10. Sometimes, udp socket doesn't work. The reason for that is, in iOS 10 they added a new setting or permission under your app that allows the user to switch on or off the user of WLAN or cellular data.

The following would appear in the settings of the app:

[image]

When I tap on the Wireless... It will bring me to this UI:

[image]

After allowing WLAN use. The app would work fine.

Now, the problem is, sometimes, or in some devices running iOS 10, the settings that I just showed you doesn't appear(I am referring to the setting shown on the first image). So, is there anything I can do to make that settings always appear? It seems that sometimes iOS system doesn't recognize that my app is using wireless data. And it would result in my app would never get to use WLAN forever.

Comment: You cannot add custom `permission` to `ios`, the permission list is define in advance: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: @aircraft Hi, thanks for the link. I wasn't trying to add any custom permission. I just want to know which info plist key corresponds to the use of WLAN. I checked the link you gave, I don't see key corresponds to the use of WLAN. Perhaps you know which one it is?

Comment: What I mean is there is no way to add custom permission in the` ios sdk`, the all permissions is pre-defined , listed in the official  link.You can not add your custom premission such as your mean of `WLAN` permission to `ios-sdk`.

Comment: @aircraft Hi, this is not any custom permission that I am try to add to the ios-sdk. This is new in ios 10, and I searched a lot and they say that this is a bug in ios 10. Some apps would ask the user for WLAN use permission, but some won't.

Comment: I am not aware of a new iOS10 feature "WLAN Permissions". Every app is alowd to use WLAN by default. The green icon in your screen-shot stays for Mobile Data, not WLAN. Plese describe more detailed what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Or do you refer to `Wireless Accessory Configuration` capability?

Comment: @shallowThought Hi, that is definitely not Mobile Data. I know what you are talking about. I just edited my question.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding each other. I haven't tried this myself yet, but this specific "permission" appearing in the Settings app does not match anything you can code in your app. There's no reason why it would have to. If the user sets this to WLAN only, your app will simply not get an internet connection unless the user is in a WLAN (so only cellular won't work). In that case you could inform them they need to allow this. I don't think there's an API to display a ready UI element for this, and I'm not sure whether you can programmatically check which exact setting the user made.

Comment: @Gero Yes, I know I can just tell the user to check the settings. But the problem is not all the time the "settings" is present. That is why I have a problem here. If that settings for switching between WLAN, WLAN & Cellular Data, would be there all the time. I wouldn't be asking this question anymore.

Comment: @finalstatic Hi, do you find a solution for this?

Comment: @srjohnhuang Hi, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a time of researching. I ended up seeking help with Apple Code Level Support. Apple states that this problem would most probably occur when you reskin your app. They say that probably it's because of the Image UUID of the main app and the reskinned app are the same. When you install both of them in your phone, the system will treat the reskinned app as the same app compared to the main app. So, if the one app fails to access WLAN, then it will also affect the other one. According to them, this appears to be **a bug in iOS**. And currently, they **don't have any solution** for the developers. This is the radar bug number:

What I did to somehow lessen the occurrence of the problem is to add tracking to the Network Restriction by using the following code.

```
- (void)startCheckingNetworkRestriction
{
    __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;

    _monitor = [[CTCellularData alloc] init];

    _monitor.cellularDataRestrictionDidUpdateNotifier = ^(CTCellularDataRestrictedState state)
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
         {
             NSString *  statusStr;

             switch(state)
             {
                 case kCTCellularDataRestrictedStateUnknown:
                 {
                     statusStr = @"restriction status:Unknown";
                 }
                     break;

                 case kCTCellularDataRestricted:
                 {
                     statusStr = @"restriction status:restricted";

                     [weakSelf performUrlSession];
                 }
                     break;

                 case kCTCellularDataNotRestricted:
                 {
                     statusStr = @"restriction status:not restricted";
                 }
                     break;

                 default:
                 {
                     abort();
                 }
                     break;
             }

             NSLog(@"Restriction state: %@", statusStr);
         }];
    };
}
```

Take note that you have to import CoreTelephony to do this.

```
@import CoreTelephony;
```

when I detect that the network is restricted. I will open a URL session to force internet access attempt and would hope that the restriction alert dialog would pop out. Once the alert is pop out, then the WLAN Access Settings that I was talking about would definitely appear under the settings. There are times that this doesn't work. If it happens, then you'll just have to rename the bundle ID, and make a couple of changes to your code and then rebuild it a couple of times (Well, that's what I did when I was experimenting this). Reinstalling the app won't do a thing. Restarting and resetting the phone won't do either.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no user permission to use WIFI in iOS10.

The application in your screenshot (BSW SMART KIT) is using Wireless Accessories (WAC), i.e. is able to connect to wireless speakers. To accomplish this the `Wireless Accessory Configuration` capability is required. This is what you can dis/enable in the systems settings (your screenshot).

The switch in the settings shows up after connecting to a device via WIFI through WAC. You can see this behaviour in your sample app (BSW SMART KIT) too.

This [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) might let you get the idea. Detailed information in [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But I think my question is still not clear for others to understand what I really need. I just edited my whole question and really focused on what I need.

Comment: How do you connect to devices?

Comment: We connect to the devices through TCP socket.

Comment: Do you have WAC activated? This is the setting you are referring to.

Comment: How do I activate that?

Comment: See the provided links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129489/discussion-between-final-static-and-shallowthought).

Comment: This is only present on devices sold in China